# Customize the space in description and add hyperref to the link

Tags: spacing, hyperref, itemize, description

I want to make the the space (shown by a  red line) equal to 1 cm. And I want to make the link shown in green color as hyperref.

[image]

This is MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\begin{document}
\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{DAFTAR PUSTAKA}

\begin{center}
{\fontsize{14}{12}\selectfont{\textbf{DAFTAR PUSTAKA}}}
\end{center}
\vspace{24pt}
\begin{description}
\item 
Abu, Maulidyani. (2018). Aliran Fluida Nano Melalui Bola Berpori dibawah Pengaruh Konveksi Campuran dan Medan Magnet. Thesis. Institute Teknologi Sepuluh Nopember
\item
Bar-Meir, Genick. (2013). Basic of Fluid Mechanics. Diperoleh dari website Metoda Elementow Skonczonych: www.feazone.org. Diakses tanggal 19 Desember 2019. 
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This seems to be a bibliography. Why not use a package dedicated to building bibliographies (such as biblatex)  instead of manually building the list of references?

Comment: @leandriis I've try to use that. But, very difficult to compile with my project. So this the best format for my project (except the sapce)

Answer (score 1):

Although I stongly recommend taking a look at a package like `biblatex` instead of manually building a bibliography, here is a suggestion based upon `enumitem` for the indentation and `hyperref` for the hyperlink and color:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\urlstyle{same}
\hypersetup{urlcolor=green}
\begin{document}
\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{DAFTAR PUSTAKA}

\begin{center}
{\fontsize{14}{12}\selectfont{\textbf{DAFTAR PUSTAKA}}}
\end{center}
\vspace{24pt}
\begin{description}[leftmargin=!,itemindent=-1cm]
\item 
Abu, Maulidyani. (2018). Aliran Fluida Nano Melalui Bola Berpori dibawah Pengaruh Konveksi Campuran dan Medan Magnet. Thesis. Institute Teknologi Sepuluh Nopember
\item
Bar-Meir, Genick. (2013). Basic of Fluid Mechanics. Diperoleh dari website Metoda Elementow Skonczonych: \url{www.feazone.org}. Diakses tanggal 19 Desember 2019. 
\end{description}
\end{document}
```